# Prevent browser's back button from reopening pop up window on previous page

Tags: javascript, browser, asp-classic, browser-history

How would I prevent the browser from opening the pop up window that was displayed from the previous page when the user clicks the back button?

I hope that made sense but I'll explain it in point form below:

There are three pages: Page1, Page2, Page3

1. User loads Page1 and clicks a link to load Page2 in a new window using JavaScript (i.e. window.open(...)). The User can close Page2 anytime they wish-- but we'll assume the user does  so before step 2.
2. User now clicks a link on Page1 to load Page3.
3. User is now on Page3 and clicks the back button on their browser.
4. Page1 is displayed in the browser but Page2 is displayed again in a pop up window.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent Page2 from popping up again. I am using classic ASP as well, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page was redirecting to itself and inserting the javascript code to pop up a new window based on the button pressed previously. I think it determined this via the post or get methods. I forget now.

As such, when the user presses the back button, they will reload the page with the embedded javascript code and not the original page.

We've since left classic ASP behind so I can't really test any suggestions but appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

If Page2 is opened as a result of clicking a link, how is it automatically being opened when the back button is clicked?  Unless Page2 is opened automatically on the initial load of Page1, it shouldn't pop up due to the back button being pressed - pressing "Back" doesn't click a link on the previous page.  I suspect something else is going on in your page - can we see some code please?

Comment: We've since abandoned classic ASP in favor of ASP.net (thank goodness). What I believe was happening was that the user would press the submit button on Page1 which then redirected to itself. Based on what button was pressed, the page would determine when to insert javascript onto the page itself to popup a new window on load. I think.

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating a session variable on page2. and check if it exist upon opening of page1. or use a cookie.

EDIT:

```
Function IsPostBack()
    IsPostBack = (Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST")
End Function
```

this will not detect a page refresh though..